# Adding Values from array - Jquery UI Sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can some one help in this as I can't figure it out. Everythign is working as it should but from some reason the addition of the values from the arrays in var mbdata are not adding up correctly. Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
var labelArr = new Array(0, 20, 75, 1500);
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  values: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: labelArr.length-1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      mbdata=labelArr[ui.value]+labelArr[$( "#slider_2" ).slider("value")]+labelArr[$( "#slider_3" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_4" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_5" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_6" ).slider( "value" )]; 
        g1.refresh(mbdata);

  }
});
});


$(function() {
var labelArr = new Array(0, 30, 75, 150);
$( "#slider_2" ).slider({
  value:0,
  min: 0,
  max: labelArr.length - 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      mbdata=labelArr[ui.value]+labelArr[$( "#slider_3" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_4" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_5" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_6" ).slider( "value" )];
        g1.refresh(mbdata);
  }

  });
});

$(function() {
var labelArr = new Array(0, 20, 100, 200);
$( "#slider_3" ).slider({
  value:0,
  min: 0,
  max: labelArr.length - 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#days" ).val( ui.value );
      $("#label_3").html(labelArr[ui.value]);
      mbdata=labelArr[ui.value]+labelArr[$( "#slider_2" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_4" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_5" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_6" ).slider( "value" )];

        g1.refresh(mbdata);

  }
});
});


$(function() {
var labelArr = new Array(0, 10, 20, 50);
$( "#slider_4" ).slider({
  value:0,
  min: 0,
  max: labelArr.length - 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#days" ).val( ui.value );
      $("#label_4").html(labelArr[ui.value]);
      mbdata=labelArr[ui.value]+labelArr[$( "#slider_2" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_3" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_5" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_6" ).slider( "value" )];

        g1.refresh(mbdata);

  }
});
});



$(function() {
var labelArr = new Array(0, 70, 140, 350);
$( "#slider_5" ).slider({
 value:0,
  min: 0,
  max: labelArr.length - 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#days" ).val( ui.value );
      $("#label_3").html(labelArr[ui.value]);
      mbdata=labelArr[ui.value]+labelArr[$( "#slider_4" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_3" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_2" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_6" ).slider( "value" )];

        g1.refresh(mbdata);

  }
});
});

$(function() {
var labelArr = new Array(0, 60, 240,600);
$( "#slider_6" ).slider({
  value:0,
  min: 0,
  max: labelArr.length - 1,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#days" ).val( ui.value );
      $("#label_6").html(labelArr[ui.value]);
      mbdata=labelArr[ui.value]+labelArr[$( "#slider_5" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_4" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_3" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider_2" ).slider( "value" )]+labelArr[$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )];

        g1.refresh(mbdata);
  }
});
});
```

If you wanna have a look at a live version: http://www.rcb.com.mt/wordpresstesting/melita/calculator/Data-Calculator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same variable name in all functions. When you declare a new array you overwrite the old one.

Try to declare arrays with different names.

Comment: When I did that, the sliders will not move for some reason.

Comment: To be honest I'm only saving and trying it on a browser, on dreamweaver I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Try to declare your arrays on the top of js file. Maybe when you use it, it isn't declare.

Comment: I decalred it outside the function & and also on top of the JS file for some reason array slider is not moving :S

Comment: It's possible to create an jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Ok I managed to get it working. The addition is working perfect but when sliding the sliders back, the value are not updating correctly

Comment: `mbdata = labelArr1[ui.value] + labelArr2[$("#slider_2").slider("value")];`

It's not the good id in your js fiddle.

Comment: Many thanks for your help I managed to solve the issue by reading deeper the api documentation. Thanks so much for your input really appreciate